# Count next n rows that meets a condition in R

Tags: r, rolling-computation

Let's say I have a df that looks like this

```
ID    X_Value
1      40
2      13
3      75
4      83
5      64
6      43
7      74
8      45
9      54
10     84
```

So what I would like to do, is to do a rolling function that if in the actual and last 4 rows, there are 2 or more values that are higher than X (let's say 70 for this example) then return 1, else 0.

So the output would be something like the following:

```
ID    X_Value  Next_4_2
1      40        0
2      13        0
3      75        0
4      83        1
5      64        1
6      43        1
7      24        1
8      45        0
9      74        0
10     84        1
```

I think this would be possible with a rolling function, but I have tried and not sure how to do it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your expected output, I suppose you meant "in the actual and previous 3 rows". Then using some rolling function indeed does the job:

```
library(zoo)
thr1 <- 70
thr2 <- 2
last <- 3 + 1
df$Next_4_2 <- 1 * (rollsum(df$X_Value > thr1, last, align = "right", fill = 0) >= thr2)
df
#    ID X_Value Next_4_2
# 1   1      40        0
# 2   2      13        0
# 3   3      75        0
# 4   4      83        1
# 5   5      64        1
# 6   6      43        1
# 7   7      74        1
# 8   8      45        0
# 9   9      54        0
# 10 10      84        1
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexing using `max(1,i-3)` is perhaps the only part of the code worth remembering. I might help in subsequent construction when a for-loop was really needed.

```
dat$X_Next_4_2 <- integer( length(dat$X_Value) )
dat$ X_Next_4_2[1]=0
for (i in 2:length(dat$X_Value) ){ 
          dat$ X_Next_4_2[i]= 
            ( sum(dat$X_Value[i: (max(0, i-4) )] >=70) >=2 )}
```

(Not very pretty and clearly inferior to the rollsum answer already posted.)